# ToggleMenuFlyoutItem tap and selection does not work in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm creating ToggleMenuFlyoutItems in code and adding them to an attached MenuFlyout's Items collection.

I set the IsTapEnabled of each to true, then add event handler to the Tapped event of each, and the tap event doesn't get fired when I tap on one of them in the list of the MenuFlyoutItem.
Also, the checked state is not visible if I set it from code.

Here is the code:

```
   //XAML code:
   <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
       <MenuFlyout x:Name="flyout" Placement="Bottom">
       </MenuFlyout>
   </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

   //C# code:
   //...loop here
   var subItem = new ToggleMenuFlyoutItem();
   subItem.Text = "Test";
   subItem.IsTapEnabled = true;
   subItem.Tapped += SubItem_Tapped;
   subItem.IsChecked = true;
   subItem.IsEnabled = true;

   flyoutMenu.Items.Add(subItem);
   //...loop end here

   //...
   private void SubItem_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Data data = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Data;

        if (data != null)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

The flyout appears when I hold an item in the list to whose elements (stackpanel) this flyout is attached, but I can't figure out why the selected state is not shown and tapped event is not called...

The same code works fine in a Windows 10 UWP app, though...

Is there anything I'm missing while settings this up?
Is it not supposed to work this way, only by adding items in the XAML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you've missed while setting this in code-behind. The problem here is that the implementation of `ToggleMenuFlyoutItem` on Windows Phone 8.1 is different from what on Windows 8.1 and also different from Windows 10 UWP apps.

Firstly, let's look at the style and template of `ToggleMenuFlyoutItem` in Windows 8.1 apps.

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleMenuFlyoutItem -->
<Style TargetType="ToggleMenuFlyoutItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleMenuFlyoutItem">
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                 </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemFocusedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemFocusedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="InnerBorder">
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph"
                                   Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                   Data="F1 M 0,58 L 2,56 L 6,60 L 13,51 L 15,53 L 6,64 z"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Height="14"
                                   Stretch="Fill"
                                   Width="16"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

We can find the default style in **generic.xaml** by searching "ToggleMenuFlyoutItem". the "generic.xaml" file comes with Windows 8.1 SDK and usually is located in ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\xaml\design*** folder. This location depends on the Windows SDK installation.

Then for the default style of `ToggleMenuFlyoutItem` in Windows Phone 8.1, we can find it in generic.xaml file in ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\abi\Xaml\Design*** folder.

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleMenuFlyoutItem -->
<Style TargetType="ToggleMenuFlyoutItem">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemThemePadding}" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleMenuFlyoutItem">
        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="PointerOver">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="PointerOver" To="Normal">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you compare with these two styles, you will find in Windows Phone 8.1, there is only a `TextBlock` in the template. But in the template in Windows 8.1, there is also a `Path` named "CheckGlyph" with the "CheckStates" `VisualStateGroup` which is used to change its visibility.

And we can find the default style and template of `ToggleMenuFlyoutItem` in Windows 10 at [ToggleMenuFlyoutItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299158.aspx). It's like what in Windows 8.1 but also have some differences.

So the selected state can be shown on Windows 10, Windows 8.1 but not on Windows Phone 8.1.

Finally, for the `Tapped` event of `ToggleMenuFlyoutItem`, it can't be raised in Windows Phone 8.1. Actually, in Windows Phone 8.1 apps, all [`MenuFlyoutItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutitem.aspx) can not raise this event. To handle the selection of a menu item, we can use [Click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutitem.click.aspx) of `MenuFlyoutItem` and `ToggleMenuFlyoutItem` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now.